# The view xxx didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: django, forms, validation

I have an error I do not understand because the logic I use in my view has not changed and works for my other project. And when I read the Django doc, my logic's view is conform: https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/topics/forms/#the-view

> We call the form’s is_valid() method; if it’s not True, we go back to the template with the form. This time the form is no longer empty (unbound) so the HTML form will be populated with the data previously submitted, where it can be edited and corrected as required.

In my form, I have validation control.
My clean method below have 3 validations controls and the control #2 raised

```
errors <ul class="errorlist"><li>__all__<ul class="errorlist nonfield"><li>Ce patient ne peut être randomisé dans ce site. Veuillez vérifier votre saisie.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

So in my understanding of the doc, it should be redirected to the completed form with errors message display (as it do usually in my project) even if there is no else condition for no valid form in my view(is_valid() == False).

What is wrong?

views.py

```
def randomization_edit(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        print("request", request.POST.dict())
        form = RandomizationEditForm(request, data=request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            # do stuff
            return redirect('randomization:confirmation', pk=randomisation.pk)

    else:
        if request.session.get('user_can_randomize'):
            form = RandomizationEditForm(request)
            return render(request, 'randomization/edit.html', {'form': form})
        else:
            return redirect("home")
```

forms.py

```
   def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(RandomizationEditForm, self).clean()
        # control #1
        if Randomisation.objects.filter(pat=self.data.get('pat').upper()).exists():
            bras = Randomisation.objects.get(pat=self.data.get('pat').upper()).bra_lib
            raise forms.ValidationError("Ce patient a déjà été randomisé dans le bras " + bras + ". Veuillez vérifier votre saisie.")
        # control #2
        if Pays.objects.get(pay_abr=self.data.get('pat').upper()[0:2]).pay_ide != int(self.data.get('pay_ide')):
            raise forms.ValidationError("Ce patient ne peut être randomisé dans ce site. Veuillez vérifier votre saisie.")
        # control #3
        if not patient_code_is_valid(self.data.get('pat').upper()):
            raise forms.ValidationError("Il y a incohérence entre le site et le pays dans le numéro patient. Veuillez vérifier votre saisie.")
        return cleaned_data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make a POST request, and the form is not valid, you do not return any result. In that casee, one normally *rerenders* the template with the form containing the errors:

```
def randomization_edit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RandomizationEditForm(request, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return redirect('randomization:confirmation', pk=randomisation.pk)
    else:
        if not request.session.get('user_can_randomize'):
            return redirect("home")
        else:
            form = RandomizationEditForm(request)
    return render(request, 'randomization/edit.html', {'form': form})
```

The `return render(…)` will thus return a HTTP response in case it is a GET requjest with a `user_can_randomize` value for the session, or in case you make a POST request, and the from is not valid.